# Play framework concepts

Tags: java, scala, web, playframework

Could someone explain how the web apps work on play framework example? The things I misunderstand:
1)Which part of the code(I mean code from examples listed on play framework site) allows many users to use the same app at same time?
2)For example I have a program : a textField, button and list. Write in textfield, press button and the text is added to the list. Every user should have own list, but where should I store the data if it's objects, in memory? In DB? In session/cookies? And how this data should be recognized, by session of? Are there any good examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read the documentation and search the web a bit more about Play to be honest. Here are a few pointers:-

- Play will use a default thread pool to serve requests. All actions are asynchronous - meaning (as long as you do not block a thread in the action) a Play app should be able to serve a large volume of requests (depending on your machine resources), as these threads get quickly reused to serve other requests
- Play is designed to be stateless so no Session (in context of Java servlet session that is). Play does not use Java servlet spec. (actually one of the original drivers Play was created was of limitations of Servlet spec)

In terms of your own application, what are you going to do with that data you have collected later? What do you need it for? That should help you determine where to store it (if at all). If you want it just for session scope then you could use session cookie - see the docs). If you want it later (ie. when user comes back to site) then you could put it in a store of some kind. Again, see the docs.

There are loads of articles on Play's architecture. And the official docs are quite good at pointing you in the right direction for most use cases.

The [Lightbend](https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-projects/play-framework) has some good resources and there are loads of [Activator](https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt) templates to provide codes samples.

Here is the simple [CRUD template](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-scala-intro) which might help you.